# Confusing incorrect question in my grammar book

Tags: grammar, transitive-verbs, intransitive-verbs

The workers _________ $1,000 to plant the trees in the garden.

A) paid
B) to pay
C) paying
D) were paid

Can you tell me which answer is right and explain why?

If here is not the right place for this question, please forward me to a forum / community where I can get such questions answered.

Comment: D is the more salient answer. If A were at all possible, it would be "The workers paid $1000 to have the trees planted ..."

Comment: @BillJ No, that's not at all right. Your rephrasing changes the meaning of the sentence completely—it says that the workers paid to have somebody *else* plant the trees, not that they paid to be able to plant the trees *themselves*. But, more importantly, I don't see why paying a fee to be able to plant trees is all that unlikely. In places, businesses pay local government to be able to "own" small parts of grass on the side of highways, where they plant flowers and trees, and they get a sign saying the landscaping belongs to them. Just because D) is more likely by no means that A) is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the passive voice:

D) The workers **were paid** $1,000 to plant the trees in the garden.

In English, the indirect object is usually more idiomatic than the direct object as the subject in the passive voice of ditransitive verbs. Therefore, instead of *$1,000 were paid to the workers to plant the trees in the garden*, it is more idiomatic to use sentence (D) above.

Comment: Syntactically, there is no reason why A) is not also possible. The workers could have paid someone to be able to plant the trees. This is no different than *I paid $20 to enter the club.* ("What's the fee to be allowed to plant trees here?" "$1,000" "Thank you, here's our money.") That's an unlikely scenario, but it's quite possible in terms of grammar.

Comment: @JasonBassford actually the book did suggest A) to be correct but because it was written in an Asian language I am not familiar with (I posted the question on behalf of someone else), I am not capable of understanding their reasoning. I have studied computational linguistics myself and understand the many different ways a sentence can parse grammatically and fully agree with both of your interpretations but in the absence of additional clarifications it sounds more probable workers receive the money to do some work than give it to others to delegate the task of doing work.

Comment: @CetinSert By far the more salient answer is D). A) is so unlikely as to be ruled out, though if it were re-worded to "The workers paid $1000 to have the trees planted ...", that would be fine.

Comment: @BillJ A grammar test that states there is only one correct answer, should *only* be about what is grammatically permissible. It should have nothing to do with what's likely or personal opinion. Otherwise, it's not possible to be objective. Only in things like philosophy or other arts where interpretation is required should people be marked on *opinion*. The grading of science (and grammar) must be based on objective criteria. In terms of grammar, A) is both grammatical and understandable.

Comment: You should consider the likely level of grammar in the OP's grammar book; it's probably quite basic, allowing for only D to be the correct answer. A is grammatically possible but semantically extremely unlikely.

Comment: @CetinSert *"Actually the book did suggest A) to be correct but because it was written in an Asian language I am not familiar with (I posted the question on behalf of someone else), I am not capable of understanding their reasoning."* If the book didn't say there was only **one** correct answer, but that there were **two** (as it should have done), that changes the question considerably, and also reinforces the point I've been trying to make. Can you add a note to the bottom of your question to indicate that the book said there were two correct answers, A) and D)?